# Weird 1d shape result on pytorch 3d ResNet

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a [3dResNet model from PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/models/generated/torchvision.models.video.r2plus1d_18.html). I also commented out the flatten line in the resnet.py source code so my output shouldn't be 1D.

Here is the code I have:

```py
class VideoModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,num_channels=3):
        super(VideoModel, self).__init__()
        self.r2plus1d = models.video.r2plus1d_18(pretrained=True)
        self.r2plus1d.fc = Identity()
        for layer in self.r2plus1d.children():
            layer.requires_grad_ = False

    def forward(self, x):
        print(x.shape)
        x = self.r2plus1d(x)
        print(x.shape)
        return x
```

My identity class exists just to ignore a layer:

```py
class Identity(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def forward(self, x):
        return x
```

When I run `torch.randn(1, 3, 8, 112, 112)` as my input, I get the following output:

```
torch.Size([1, 3, 8, 112, 112])
torch.Size([1, 512, 1, 1, 1])
```

Why do I have a 1D output even though I removed fc layer and the flatten operation?
Is there a better way to remove the flatten operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is the `AdaptiveAvgPool3d` layer right before the flatten step. It is called with the argument `output_size=(1,1,1)`, and so pools the last three dimensions to `(1,1,1)` regardless of their original dimensions.

In your case, the output after the average pool has the shape `(1,512,1,1,1)`, after flatten has the shape `(1,512)`, and after the fc layer has the shape `(1,400)`.

So the flatten operation is not responsible, disable the average pool and all subsequent steps to get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. As a follow up I'm assuming editing the source code isn't a good practice. Any better way to remove the pooling or am I stuck with my current method?

Comment: @Alex I am not sure of the best practice but one way would be to write your own `forward` function for `VideoModel` that explicitly only passes the input through the layers you want it to (i.e., call `self.r2plus1d.layer1`, etc. explicitly). Then you don't need to change the library source code or duplicate it.